# Does SQL Server TLS1.1 support only come bundled with TLS 1.2 support in 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tls-1.2

I strongly suspect that Microsoft introduced TLS 1.1 support in 2008 R2 in the same updates that they introduced TLS 1.2 support but I can't find any documented evidence of this. I understand that TLS 1.2 is strongly encouraged and I expect to get responses to this effect but in some cases this is not my decision to make. What I need in asking this question is positive or negative confirmation that is stronger than my own hunch.

Comment: Did you see this one, especially the values in column `First build that supports TLS 1.2`? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: What I would like to find is an equivalent column that says something like "First build that supports TLS 1.1"

Comment: I understand what you are looking for but I could not find one. Another note it appears support for 1.2 was available in 2008 but may be was ported back after introduced in 2008R2.